# Using jQuery to search for JavaScript assigned values to an object

Tags: jquery, selection

I know this question is a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find anything about it because I can't seem to phrase the right question.

I am working with MapBox.js and created a marker that has a button in its popup message that lets you delete the marker displaying the popup.  I got the code, which works, from Stack Overflow, but is uses a class to locate the marker, and I want to assign a property/attribute, whatever, to the marker that I can use to specifically locate the one marker that has it.  I did this using the regular JavaScript object member assignment:

```
marker.uniqueID = Date.now().toString();
```

and then assigned the marker.uniqueID to delete button in the popup message.
I've used the Chrome inspector and can see these assigned values in the marker object and in the delete button html element.  However, when I tried to find the map marker using the button's assigned value:

```
$( '.marker-delete-button[uniqueID="12345"]')
```

I get back an empty list of matches using the above and several other selectors.  So to simplify this I created the following code, which gets the same results:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.clear();
      var obj1 = { text: 'obj1' };
      var obj2 = { text: 'obj2' };
      var obj3 = { text: 'obj3' };

      obj1.a=1;
      obj2.a=2;
      obj3.a=3;

      var $a = $.attr( 'a' );
      console.log( $a );
      console.log( obj1 );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, where am I going wrong?  I understand that I should be able to search for JavaScript arrays and objects having particular a property/attribute with a specific value, but I can't seem to make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery searches the **DOM** for a matching element, not arbitrary objects ?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't what jQuery is good for, and this almost certainly isn't practical or possible

Comment: You aren't showing any of the relevant code that generates the markers and stores the marker data array

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the MapBox.js, as it is new to me. It looks very interesting. I tried to understand the problem you have.

But, first, let me respond to the simplified sample code you posted. Better to make sure that jQuery has loaded, before you use it.

```
$(function() {
});
```

The following code adds two attributes 'a' and 'b' to `<body>` DOM element. You can inspect it in Firefox.

```
var body = $("body").attr( 'a', 'avalue');
console.log(body);      
body.attr( 'b', 'bvalue');
console.log(body);
```

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do with following. It didn't change any of the html elements.

```
var $a = $.attr('a');
console.log($a);
```

Were you hoping that it adds an attribute to the `<html>` DOM element so that you can select it later using jQuery like the following and run some code on the resulting "this" object?

```
$('[a]').function() {
});
```